# Proper unit testing with PostSharp

Tags: c#, unit-testing, aop, postsharp

What is the proper way to unit test classes which use PostSharp aspects ?
Example:

```
class MyViewModel
{
   [AsyncOperationInformView]
   public async Task DoSmth()
   {
     ... code
   }
}
```

I thought I could unit test my `AsyncOperationInformView` aspect and then add unit test in `MyViewModel` to check is aspect "appended" to method `DoSmth()` (without testing aspect logic in view model tests). Is it valid and good approach? If so how to do that (how to check is aspect "appended") ? If not - why it's bad idea and what's the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to use PostsSharp and had the same thought.

For unit testing, you will need to build without PostSharp, then, build with PostSharp weaving for acceptance testing.

You might, if it's appropriate, assert that the annotation `AsyncOperationInformView` is present, but don't test for it's behaviour as this is the responsibility of higher level testing.

Comment: I think it's a bad idea to differentiate between "postsharped" and "non-postsharped" code for different testing points. I highly recommend having all your tests run against the final (postsharped) code; otherwise you're not getting all the value you can out of your automated testing tools. It also gives you false confidence: the unit tests can pass and there could be major problems in the "real" code.

Comment: @mcating There is a fundamental difference between unit testing and integration\acceptance testing.  Unit testing on a non-PostSharp build is no different than unit testing on a debug build.  Obviously, acceptance testing needs to be on the release\PostSharped build.  Fex is looking at unit testing in his question.

Comment: BanksySan - sure I can build without PostSharp but I lose "test cases" and important tests could be missed - do you have any solution ?

Comment: @fex You won't, not if you are unit testing.  The unit test will assert the functionality of a single unit will work.  You are not testing if PostSharp works, only the code you have written and only that code in isolated (class-sized) chunks.

Comment: @fex If you are testing whether your aspect will fire when you run your method, then this is integration\acceptance\joined-up testing (it's name depends on your testing strategy).  In this case then you need PostSharp turned on, but you have no mocking so there is no concern any more.  You are now testing behaviours at the interface of you application.

Comment: @BanskSan: I recommend running unit tests only on release builds as well. :) I understand exactly what you're saying (I'm very quality oriented), and I write my aspects to use IoC to insert mocks into the aspects and confirm they're correctly called. Example: Say someone accidentally turns off the "Enable Postsharp" project options. If the aspects are logging-oriented, it's quite possible it would be weeks before someone notices logging stopped working on a deployed system. A unit test would find it within minutes. Therefore I can test that "postsharp works" as well as the decorated code.

Comment: @mcating Some unit tests will _probably_ fail with PostSharp turned on which can generate phantom bugs.  Acceptance tests will confirm logging is working, if you are testing logging functionality in your test then it is not a unit test.  Remember what you are testing, are you testing PostSharp works, or that your units work?

Comment: @BanskySan: A PostSharp aspect is user code, and can be tested with a unit test. (Just attach it to a class/method defined in your unit test that has no other purpose than to exercise the aspect.) I believe two unit tests are required: one to confirm your aspect works, and one to confirm your attached class works. I think we're way off-topic here, so I propose we agree to disagree...

Answer (score 3):

In answer to your "Is this is a good idea?", I think it very much is.

1) I believe you should run every test against the code you plan to ship with. If PostSharp is involved, then the unit tests you run should test against the PostSharp-weaved assemblies. Otherwise, you're spending build and dev time testing unused, intermediate, or throwaway assemblies. The same thinking applies to running automated tests against debug vs. release (I always run all tests against release). If you have plenty of build time, you can run against both if you really, really want to. However, it is absolutely essential to test the code you will deploy if you need to choose.

2) I believe it is a good idea to confirm every "rule" via automated testing. If you have a requirement that every method is decorated with an aspect, write an automated test that confirms that every method is decorated with that aspect. Running an automated reflection-based test against an assembly is very cheap relative to the potential cost of noticing a bug, tracking down the offending function, then realizing someone forgot to follow the rule two years in the future.

In answer to the "how do you do it?" part of your question, I just solved a similar problem to determine if a class was decorated with a specific PostSharp aspect. Stackoverflow question/answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070246/how-to-determine-if-a-class-is-decorated-with-a-postsharp-aspect-at-build-or-run/24088757#24088757).

An easy way to solve this is to decorate your Aspect with MulticastAttributeUsage:

```
[Serializable]
[MulticastAttributeUsage(PersistMetaData = true)]
public class MyMethodAspectAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect
{
}
```

When you use the aspect on a method, it will emit a System.Attribute into your assembly and add that to the custom attributes on your method. From there, you can simply query for that custom attribute in your unit tests:

```
[Test]
public void ConfirmAspectAttached()
{
   var serviceType = typeof( MyViewModel );
   var member = serviceType.GetMembers().Where( member.Name == "DoSmth" ).FirstOrDefault(); // probably a better way of doing this

   Assert.IsNotNull( member );

   Assert.IsTrue( member.GetCustomAttributes(true).Any(attrib => attrib.GetType() == typeof(MyMethodAspectAttribute )));
}
```